# Bayesian Inference in Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to perform bayesian inference between two data sets in python for example

```
x = [9, 11, 12, 4, 56, 32, 45], y = [23, 56, 78, 13, 27, 49, 89]
```

I have looked through numerous pages of documentation and found that pymc https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelfitting.html#markov-chain-monte-carlo-the-mcmc-class and bayespy http://bayespy.org/en/latest/examples/gmm.html are probably my best bets but the documentation is incredibly hard to suss.

I am trying to predict what the the value of y would be, dependant on the value of x and the strength of correlation between the two datasets.

Thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: what you have described appears to be simple regression problem . even this example would be sufficient : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-ols-py

Comment: Predicting the value of y based on the value of x and judging strength of correlation sounds very much like regression. Not necessarily linear, could be a more complex model behind it. How would you want to MCMC for something like this. It is usually used for sequences. You could consider x to be a sequence and train a model to predict new digits based on the predecessors. Then you could theoretically look at y as a sequence and calculate the predicted number for every place in y, given the digits before it. But your dataset is much too small. The digits in y don't even occur in x.

Comment: I am trying to predict the next value of y (and those thereafter) dependent on the relationship between the two datasets. I want to use an MCMC algorithm to improve the accuracy of the prediction by removing the significance of the 'noise' (or anomalous results) between the datasets

Comment: how big is your dataset ? how many training sequences do you have and how long are they ?

Comment: My datasets are 10 entries long and sorry what do you mean by training sequences?

Comment: How many datasets do you have ? How many digits are there, in total, in your dataset ?

Comment: So I just want to do this procedure between two datasets that have 10 floats each, I do have 440 in total that all need to be compared between each other.

Comment: And all of those sets are different ? Or do they follow the same rules ? What I mean is: Looking at the first 100 sets, could you use knowledge from those sets to make predictions for other sets ? You should add additional information to your question. About the process involved, the exact structure of the dataset, etc

Comment: So there are 20 countries and 16 datasets within each. I am looking at how each of these 16 datasets affect each other, so how dataset 1 affects dataset 2, how 2 affects 3, how 3 affects 1 etc

Comment: The predictions from other sets wouldn't really be useful in predicting others

Answer (score 0):

Markov Chains are sequences, where the probabilities of items in the sequence depend on their predecessors.

Let's assume that you have a very long list x, containing digits.
You could define that every digit depends on the two digits before it. Then you train a model:

- Input are two digits
- Output is a vector of probabilities: For every digit, how likely is it to come next.

You can use this model to generate new sequences:
Start with two digits. Then use the model to predict probabilities for the next digit, pick the most likely one. You always feed your model with the last two digits in the sequence and append new digits based on the prediction.

This can also be used to judge the probability of an existing sequence. You go through that sequence step by step, look at every digit and use your model to compute how likely this digit is, given its predecessors.

The key part here is the model. In order to use it, you need to train it with existing data. For sequences, the most common example is characters in a text. You train a model to predict the next character, based on the preceding characters. For example (here the model sees 3 preceding characters):

- "Hel" -> "l" has a high probability
- "ell" -> "o" has a high probability

The dependencies between characters are very complex, just think about the number of possible input sequences. Ideally, the model should have seen all of those sequences at some point during training. Which is impossible of course, but to get good results you need to have as much training data as possible.

If you want us to answer your question, we need more details.

1. Precise information about the dataset
2. Information about the process you're trying to model.

> So there are 20 countries and 16 datasets within each. I am looking at how each of these 16 datasets affect each other, so how dataset 1 affects dataset 2, how 2 affects 3, how 3 affects 1 etc

So the datasets have some effect on each other ?

But then you say:

> The predictions from other sets wouldn't really be useful in predicting others

This just doesn't make sense.
You can't do sequence modeling with so little data. And if the datasets have no structure, if you can't learn a general pattern by looking at the totality, then there won't be any use in comparing individual pairs.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, all 16 datasets within each country are inter related, so say set 1 has an affect on set 2, this means that set 3 will then be affected as set 2 has been too

Comment: What are these sets ? Is it always the same data, recorded in different regions or at different times. Is x and y the same data. I'm not sure whether modeling this as a sequence even makes sense. Does x[1] depend on x[0] ?

Comment: So each set is a different parameter (say GDP and household income) and each entry is the value for a different year, so x(0) may be 2007, x(1) 2008 etc. All sets have the same years as entries. So x(1) does depend on x(0) and so on

Comment: I've had a further look at some documentation and I'm looking to perform something similar to this: 
http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/06/14/frequentism-and-bayesianism-4-bayesian-in-python/
It takes the data and then performs MCMC on it, I am struggling however to apply it to what I want to do (i.e. predict values rather than plot it)